# Recomendations for simultaneous use interactive drawing application for iPADs

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, ios

I need to tutor my nephew in algebra.  He's 3000 miles away.  We both have iPads.  Skype or the phone can handle the voice channel.

I would like an application with the following:

1. Each of us can draw on our ipad at the same time, Whatever we draw appears on the other screen.
2. Option for different colors.  E.g. He draws in black, I draw in red.
3. Ability for either person to erase/modify their work, with a toggle to switch between 'erase mine' vs 'erase evertything under the eraser'
4. Ability to hit a one button save/mail screen.
5. Ability to scroll/magnify screen.  Each iPad has a several viewport on the canvas.
6. Ability to snap and crop a picture and paste into screen.
7. Inexpensive.

In essence, I want to set him a problem, or allow him to snap a picture of a problem.  Then while he works it, I can 'red-line' places where he has made an error, taken an invalid shortcut, etc.  He can correct his error, leaving my redline, I can then check and remove my redline.

Nice to have:

- Multiple sessions so I can work with several students at once.
- Handwriting recognition that turns scrawled math into typeset equations.

So far the programs I've found have one or more of the following limitations:

- A:  Only one person can draw at a time.
- B:  Only one color can be in use at a time.
- C:  You can't erase.
- D:  Your canvas is limited to one screen
- E:  Interaction is limited to WiFi.
- F:  Interaction is one way:  It's essentially a presentation tool.

Answer (score 1):

I think [FlockDraw](http://www.flockdraw.com) would be the best app for you. Although it is a web app, you could use it on an iPad by downloading a free Flash browser such as [Puffin Web Browser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/puffin-web-browser-free/id472937654?mt=8).

### List of Features:

- draw online
- unlimited people in a room
- updates in real time
- different colors
- different shapes
- eraser
- ability to draw lines
- one click saving
- full screen mode
- gallery to save and upload images
- ability to type and draw
- chat

### In response to your limitations and requirements:

**A**: Only one person can draw at a time. - *Two or more people can draw*

**B**: Only one color can be in use at a time. - *The large variety of colors allow for more than people to draw with different colors*

**C**: You can't erase. - *Eraser is provided.*

**D**: Your canvas is limited to one screen - *Well, each person can see the same screen so yes they are limited to it. If they wanted to, they could erase their canvas and start with a new one (Not sure what this is asking)*

**E**: Interaction is limited to WiFi. - *When you create a session, you are given an unique URL. You can share that URL and allow more than one person to join you session (This does not have to be through Wi-Fi)*

**F**: Interaction is one way: It's essentially a presentation tool. *Two people can draw at the same time.*

**1**. Each of us can draw on our iPad at the same time, Whatever we draw appears on the other screen. *Yes, drawing simultaneously is a feature.*

**2**. Option for different colors. E.g. He draws in black, I draw in red. *There are lots of colors to choose from*

**3**. Ability for either person to erase/modify their work, with a toggle to switch between 'erase mine' vs 'erase evertything under the eraser' *Sorry, don't think this is on here. There is only one eraser that has the ability to erase everything.*

**4**. Ability to hit a one button save/mail screen. *Yes, you can save the canvas.*

**5**. Ability to scroll/magnify screen. Each iPad has a several viewport on the canvas. *You may be able to; I haven't tried it on an iPad*

**6**. Ability to snap and crop a picture and paste into screen. *As you are on an iPad, this feature is included, but it may be harder to do on the iPad. But yes, there is a gallery.*

**7**. Inexpensive. - *It is completely free online*

**Note**: There is an iPad/iPhone app, but I'm not sure that it is better than the web app. It also costs $2.99.

Comment: Sherwood, I am curious to know if this answer helped you at all or not. If not, please tell me what is wrong and I can try to help.